# How do I validate past purchases that are not an IAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, tvos

Is it possible to validate a user's separate song purchase on iTunes from within my independent iOS or tvOS app?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. An app can only validate or know about its own purchases. Apple (thankfully) does not allow an app to obtain any information of any kind about a user's other purchases. In fact, an app doesn't know anything about the current user (not their name, not their email, not their Apple ID, etc.).